# What is the phrase "its articulation" connected to?

Tags: meaning-in-context, semantic-roles

> This constitutive element of the modern world (man, as the producer of rational hypotheses) and (1) its articulation with (2) the ideology of techno-scientific progress and (3) the development of the machine that transforms the methods and theories of natural sciences finally led to the replacement of religious and metaphysical dogmas by the blind faith to the dogma of technical and scientific progress.

Is the phrase (1) "its articulation with" connected to both (2) *the ideology* **and** (3) *the development*, or just to (2) *the ideology*?

I am very confused.  What is the phrase "its articulation" connected to?  Could you help me clarify it?  Thanks.

Comment: You should cite the source of this text.

Answer (score 0):

The antecedent of **its** is **element**. The preposition **with** has two objects, **ideology** and **development**. The verb **led** has a compound subject, **...constitutive element ... and ... its articulation with...**

The constitutive element of the modern world { ... }
 and
its articulation with    {...ideology...and...development...}

led

to the replacement of religious and metaphysical dogmas

by  {the blind faith to} <sup>[sic]</sup> the dogma of technical and scientific progress